# Boot my Mac into External USB Ubuntu Server 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot, server, mac

I recently downloaded ubuntu server 12.10 and created an install disk. I then proceeded to boot into the disk and install the server onto an external usb flash drive. After the installation was complete it ejected the disk and rebooted the computer as normal but through all my efforts i cant boot into the flash drive. I am running a 2011 macbook pro with mountain lion, 4gb of ram, 1tb hard drive, and an intel I7 processor

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting and immediately press and hold the Option key to access Startup Manager, then select your boot device.
Try different usb ports if that doesn't work. Some USB devices have better compatibility than others.

[Support.apple page for usb booting](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948)

Comment: I have restarted and accessed the boot manager and i have tried all of my usb ports but it wont even recognize the drive as a bootable drive.

Comment: You could try PLOP to first boot from a cd then directly from usb. [Pen Drive linux Page for USB booting from CD](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/category/usb-boot-cds/)  There may be an issue with the compatibility your USB device. There are some troubleshooting steps near the bottom of that support.apple page. Otherwise you may simply need to change your BIOS or UEFI boot settings to allow the USB to boot before the hard drive.

Comment: Even with the processes described i cant boot from the usb drive. The Plop disk could find and try to boot from it but gets an error and fails, it dosnt find a bootable file system. Mac boot manager wont even recognize its their.

Comment: I created an rEFIt boot disk booted into it, it seamed to recognize the usb flash drive and the ubuntu software on it but when i try and boot it with the rEFIt it will force boot me into the windows partition on my internal hard drive

Comment: Booting from USB appears to be a thorn in the side of mac users for quite some time now. Try calling apple support on the phone, supposedly they have excellent customer service.  Here is a link describing [how to contact Apple](https://www.apple.com/contact/).